# Magento2 - Get Value of New Column in Tier Price Table

Tags: magento-2.1, price, tierprice, override-model, abstract-class

I have added a new column **"admin_user"** column in `catalog_product_entity_tier_price` table. This column value needs to come when following method is executed.

```
$p=$productRepo->get('sample');
$tier=$p->getTierPrices();
foreach ($tier as $t)
{   
    print_r($t->getData())."<br>";
}
```

But `getData()` method returns only qty and customer group id.

```
Array ( [customer_group_id] => 2 [value] => 3.0500 [qty] => 1.0000 )
Array ( [customer_group_id] => 3 [value] => 4.0000 [qty] => 1.0000 )
```

<strike>How do I add **"admin_user"** value to this `getData()` method. Any help would be appreciated.</strike>

**Update 1**

I have found that in `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Attribute\Backend\GroupPrice\AbstractGroupPrice.php` columns are set in this method

```
public function loadPriceData($productId, $websiteId = null)
    {
        $connection = $this->getConnection();

        $columns = [
            'price_id' => $this->getIdFieldName(),
            'website_id' => 'website_id',
            'all_groups' => 'all_groups',
            'cust_group' => 'customer_group_id',
            'price' => 'value'
           'admin_user'=>'admin_user'            
        ];
```

How to override this method of the abstract class to include additional table columns in custom module

Answer (score 0):

for magento2.2, the loadPriceData function changed a little bit.

```
public function loadPriceData($productId, $websiteId = null)
{
    $select = $this->getSelect($websiteId);
    $productIdFieldName = $this->getProductIdFieldName();
    $select->where("{$productIdFieldName} = ?", $productId);

    $this->_loadPriceDataSelect($select);

    return $this->getConnection()->fetchAll($select);
}
```

I use plugin to include the additional column.

di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Attribute\Backend\GroupPrice\AbstractGroupPrice">
    <plugin sortOrder="1" name="PLUGINNAME"
            type="VENDERNAME\MODULENAME\Plugin\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Attribute\Backend\GroupPrice\AbstractGroupPricePlugin"/>
</type>
```

AbstractGroupPricePlugin.php

```
<?php
namespace VENDERNAME\MODULENAME\Plugin\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Attribute\Backend\GroupPrice;
class AbstractGroupPricePlugin
{
public function afterGetSelect(\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Attribute\Backend\GroupPrice\AbstractGroupPrice $subject, $result)
{
    //add admin_user column to select
    $result->columns('admin_user');
    return $result;
}
}
```

May need set extension_attribute depend on requirement.

Answer (score 0):

So I have the same problem. I have add a new column to tierprices table and I'm trying to get the value from this column from each tierprice to frontend. Can anyone help me how can I do it that?
Because now I get
Array ( [customer_group_id] => 2 [value] => 3.0500 [qty] => 1.0000 )
Array ( [customer_group_id] => 3 [value] => 4.0000 [qty] => 1.0000 )

and I want to get
Array ( [customer_group_id] => 2 [value] => 3.0500 [qty] => 1.0000 [date_to] =>'23-4-2022' )
Array ( [customer_group_id] => 3 [value] => 4.0000 [qty] => 1.0000 [date_to] =>'23-4-2022' )

Magento 2.4